# Sequelizejs is not associated to

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I made some associate but it did not work, probably with me that something is wrong, ask for help.
There are two models

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
var pages_lang = require('./pages_lang')(sequelize, DataTypes);
return sequelize.define('pages', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        references :  { model: "pages_lang", key: "page_id" }
    },
    name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    published: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '0'
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    },
    updatedAt: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            this.hasMany(models.pages_lang, {onDelete: 'SET NULL', onUpdate: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'page_id', as: 'pages', through: models.pages_lang});
        },
        getAll() {
            return this.findAll({include: [{model: pages_lang, as: 'pages_lang'}]}).then(function (result) {
                return result;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

};

```
module.exports = function (sequelize, DataTypes) {
return sequelize.define('pages_lang', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true
    },
    page_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER(10),
        allowNull: false,
        references :  { model: "pages", key: "id" }
    },
    content: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        allowNull: false
    }
}, {
    classMethods: {
        associate: function (models) {
            this.belongsTo(models.pages, {foreignKey: 'id', foreignKeyConstraint:true, as: 'pages', through: models.pages});
        }
    }
});
```

};

But when you call results in an error

> Unhandled rejection Error: pages_lang (pages_lang) is not associated
>   to pages!

Advance very grateful for the help

Comment: Welcome to SO. The standard is to post code inline to your questions, so that questions are not at risk of losing information for future readers should these external links get removed in the future. 4 spaces formats a line as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your association alias (`as`) should match what you pass to `findAll`

```
this.hasMany(models.pages_lang, {onDelete: 'SET NULL', onUpdate: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'page_id', as: 'pages_lang' });

return this.findAll({include: [{model: pages_lang, as: 'pages_lang'}]});
```

Since the model is already called `pages_lang`, you can also skip the alias completely:

```
this.hasMany(models.pages_lang, {onDelete: 'SET NULL', onUpdate: 'CASCADE', foreignKey: 'page_id'});

return this.findAll({include: [pages_lang]});
```

Notice that I removed the `through` argument - it should only be used for `belongsToMany` (many-to-many)